# Android SQLite Triggers and Views?

Tags: android, sql, triggers, view

I am confused on the whole trigger and view thing I am guessing that the triggers is used to query things from multiple tables into one table, correct me if I am wrong, and I have no idea what the view would be used for. I have searched some what on what they are used for in android but have not got the answer that I am looking for. Could some one please explain these to me or give me a place that explains them plus an example on how to use them would be nice to.

Comment: firstly i dont understand what is relevant to android or sqlite. Are you asking these for just sqlite? Whatever, trigger is procedural code that is automatically executed in response to certain events on a particular table in a database. Triggers can restrict access to specific data, perform logging, or audit data modifications. Basically when you make a transaction on a table (insert, delete, update) it supports relevant transaction for another table(s). View is a virtual table based on the result-set of an SQL statement.

Comment: @MustafaGüven: That would make quite a good answer to Christian's question.

Comment: @Mustafa Guven, I just figured I am using android and sqlite. So a trigger is not in place of a foreign key? If a view is a temporary table, can it be used to select a surten section from the database and stick it into a view? Like say the user has the option to choose to view a section of selected dates would the view be used for that?

Comment: @Christian: Please have a read of some SQL introductory material! - A database can be queried to return the desired information with the SELECT statement; no view is needed for that. Triggers are probably nothing for you to worry about; you won't need/use them. (Does SQLite support triggers/stored procs anyway?)

Answer (score 2):

**Stored Procedure:**

Stored procedures are one of numerous mechanisms of encapsulating database logic in the database. They are similar to regular programming language procedures in that they take arguments, do something, and sometimes return results and sometimes even change the values of the arguments they take when arguments are declared as output parameters

**View:**

Views are one of the greatest things invented since sliced bread. The main beauty of a view is that it can be used like a table in most situations, but unlike a table, it can encapsulate very complex calculations and commonly used joins. It can also use pretty much any object in the db except for stored procedures. Views are most useful when you always need to join the same set of tables say an Order with an Order Detail to get summary calculation fields etc.

**Trigger**:

Triggers are objects generally tied to a table or view that run code based on certain events such as inserting data, before inserting data, updating/deleting data and before these events happen.

I stole it from [here](http://www.paragoncorporation.com/ArticleDetail.aspx?ArticleID=28).